# Overriding method in a different namespace C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, namespaces, polymorphism, overriding

I have two classes in different projects.

The first, named `GeneralConcept` is at the namespace `I.am.here` and has a `protected virtual` method named `DoSomething`.

The second is named `SpecificInstanceOfConcept` and is at the namespace `I.am.in.a.different.place` and inherits from `GeneralConcept`.

I am trying to override the method. Have the same name, same inputs, same type and inheriting from the class where the method is implemented. However,
I keep getting an error saying

> no suitable method to override

The way it is set up looks like this,

```
namespace I.am.here  
{ 
    public class GeneralConcept        
    {
        //stuff
        protected virtual MyType DoSomething(Inputs input)
        {
             //more stuff
        }
    }
}


namespace I.am.in.a.different.place  
{ 
   public class SpecificInstanceOfConcept : I.am.here.GeneralConcept
    {
        //yet more stuff
        protected override MyType DoSomething(Inputs input)
        {
             //even more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* example of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overriding across namespaces should not be an issue.  That error indicates one of the following:

- `I.am.here.GeneralConcept.DoSomething` is not marked as `virtual`, `abstract`, or `override`
- `I.am.here.GeneralConcept.DoSomething` is not `public` or `protected`
- the input (or output) type to `I.am.here.GeneralConcept.DoSomething` is different than your override.

Comment: ...The friggen inputs! They have *exactly* the same text in them. But, the types are different because in one namespace the type class is also being overwritten. I was about to reply that of course the inputs are the same, hit me while I was looking at it. Thank you.